# How did the Yakuza know the identity of the shooter?

Tags: tv, the-man-in-the-high-castle

In the TV series *The Man in the High Castle*, episode "Kindness" (S1E09), Inspector Kido is asked by Taishi Okamura (of the Yakuza) to meet to discuss something. In this meeting, it is revealed that the person who shot the Crown Prince

> is a Nazi agent.

A snippet of dialogue from the meeting:

> *Okamura*: I believe you have pursued a false suspect to disguise a truth you have known from the start: that the assassin is a Nazi agent. If it were known that a Nazi fired at our Prince, that would be an act of war, a war many in the Reich would be happy to see but one our empire would almost certainly lose.
>
> *CI Kido*: I do not deny your accusation, nor will I confirm it.
>
> *Okamura*: I don't need you to, Chief Inspector. **You see, I have the name of the assassin, the real assassin.**
>
> *CI Kido*: Name your price.

<sup>Script from "Kindness" - S1E09 (emphasis mine)</sup>

How did Taishi Okamura know the identity of the shooter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not read the book yet, but a full text search for "Okamura" and "Yakuza" got me nowhere.  Looks like much of that storyline is "whole cloth."

Therefore, we only have what we see in the show to guide us, and there isn't much;  the Yakuza appear out of nowhere, and disappear just as easily.

So we're stuck with speculation based on two episodes.

Originally, Taishi only attempts to gain a bribe in return for the film itself, hoping to play both sides into getting double the cash.  When CI Kido refuses to play ball, Taishi decides to kidnap Kido's targets as well.

It's possible that Taishi **doesn't actually know who the shooter is**, but he's shown himself willing to play hardball, and if there's one thing Kido can't have flying around is any suspicion that his suspect was NOT the shooter.  Even more important than the film.  He won't pay a ransom for the film, but the security of the state, and keeping Japan out of a war it will lose, is worth anything to Kido,

> even his life.

It's also possible that **Taishi provided the weapon.**  Being the leader of the Yakuza would make it easy for Taishi to provide a weapon to the Nazis.  Kido is very careful to destroy all evidence

> when he finally locates the real shooter, a Nazi agent. Remember, having a functional gun, for any non-Japanese, is illegal.  The Nazi would need to disguise himself as an American in order to get his shot off, so he would need assistance in getting a gun in place, and the most likely source to do so is the Yakuza.  As such, Taishi could know the identity of the real shooter.

Finally, way in speculation land, **Taishi could have figured it out with the I Ching**.  In this universe, the I Ching actually DOES make accurate predictions of events, and leads the Trade Minister in the same way that

> Hitler uses the films to avoid mistakes made by his counterpart in our universe.

It's easy enough for me to believe that Taishi would have also figured out the power of I Ching, and used it to make the Yakuza so powerful.

If I were to pick one, I'd go with **Taishi bluffing** and **Kido not able or willing to call that bluff**.  World War III is in the balance, and it's worth anything for Kido to prevent it.  The Yakuza are not scared of the Kempetai, they respect nothing but force, or money.  To silence them, you pay them off.  It's also a way for us to see how important this is for Kido.  He's a straight shooter, he doesn't bend, and he doesn't negotiate... but that's a rule he'll bend for this.

Comment: +1 Nice Points... I too initially thought that Taishi was probably bluffing in order for some leverage over the Kempeitai, regarding the impounding of Yakuza-operated ships smuggling heroin, but the discovery of the shooter swayed me to believe otherwise.

Comment: And your point about the Yakuza selling the weapon to the shooter is interesting too. However, while I agree to it possibly being sold, I doubt the Yakuza would sell a gun to a Nazi agent knowingly, given the potential ramifications to the Japanese empire. If the weapon was indeed sold to the shooter it was probably sold, as you mention, to a Nazi agent impersonating an American.

Comment: @ImClarky I'd thought about the ramifications, too, but remember: criminal underworlds don't care about the government above them, as long as they can keep them at arm's reach. Even if the Nazis took over the West, it'd just be a new set of bureaucrats they have to graft, a new set of laws they have to avoid. Unless you believe that the Gestapo would be significantly more effective than the Kempetai... I'm not 100% convinced, but also we don't really see the Gestapo do much in Season 1 of the show or in the book.

Comment: I watched some of season 2 last night... you could be right :D

Answer (score 1):

In Season 2 it is revealed that,

> The Yakuza were feeding information to the Nazis. This is confirmed when Kido is investigating the burnt down barn and the farmers confirms that Okamura was there before Kido was.

Therefore, Okamura was not bluffing and likely was involved from the very beginning.